# Can I repeat a string format descriptor in python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

In fortran, I am able to repeat a format descriptor to save rewriting it many times, for example:

```
write(*,'(i5,i5,i5,i5,i5)')a,b,c,d,e
```

could be rewritten as

```
write(*,'(5(i5))')a,b,c,d,e
```

Can a similar approach be used in python?

For example, say I wanted to do the same in python, I would have to write:

```
print "{0:5d} {1:5d} {2:5d} {3:5d} {4:5d}".format(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Is there some way to repeat the format descriptor, like in fortran?

Comment: In python you can perform multiplication operations on strings, so if you were to do print 5*"string", it would print the string 5 times.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can repeat the formatting string itself:

```
print ('{:5d} '*5).format(*values)
```

Format string is a normal string, so you can [multiply it by int](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Strings#Numerical)

```
>>> '{:5d} '*5
'{:5d} {:5d} {:5d} {:5d} {:5d} '
```

Comment: Thank you.  For future reference: this works when using the formatting expression syntax as well: `print(("%6.2f"*3 + "%7.2f"*2) % ( *values ))` - note the brackets around the format string when adding multiple groups of different length.

Comment: In Python 3.6.1 `print ('{:5d} '*5).format(1,2,3,4,5)` gives an attribute error. `print ('{:5d} '*5.format(1,2,3,4,5))` gives a syntax error. However,  `fmt = '{:5d} '*5` followed by `print (fmt.format(1,2,3,4,5))` prints as desired.

Comment: `print (...).format(...)` tries to call a format method on the object returned by print(). `print ('{:5d} '*5.format(1,2,3,4,5))` tries to call a method `format()` from the integer 5. You could use `print (('{:5d} '*5).format(1,2,3,4,5))` to get it right.

Comment: for a more generic approach try: `print (('{}, '*len(s)).format(*s))` where `s` is your list of items to be printed